# Python API and sql, which is not working as expected, wrong data in sqlite

Tags: python, json, api, sqlite

I wrote last night this code, but something is not working properly.

Script is inserting every minute data in SQLite, but as probably I have wrong SQL query, script is inserting wrong data, please see attached screenshot.
I think problem is with SQLite query but not sure.

Screen shot you will be able to find here:

[image]

```py
import urllib.request
import sqlite3
import json
import time
import pandas as pd


# Unix format for time
unixstarttime = time.time()
url='http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip='
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()
   
# parse json object
obj = json.loads(data)

# THIS IS JUST A TEST, THIS PRINTING FINE, NOT SURE WHY IS NOT CORRECT VALUE IN SQL QUERY :(
print(obj["geoplugin_latitude"])

sqlcreatedb=""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS responses( 
    timestamp,
    ipaddress TEXT,
    status TEXT,
    delay TEXT,
    credit TEXT,
    city TEXT,
    region TEXT,
    regionCode TEXT,
    regionName TEXT,
    areaCode TEXT,
    dmaCode TEXT,
    countryCode TEXT,
    countryName TEXT,
    inEU TEXT,
    euVATrate TEXT,
    continentCode TEXT,
    continentName TEXT,
    latitude TEXT,
    longitude TEXT,
    locationAccuracyRadius TEXT,
    timezone TEXT,
    currencyCode TEXT,
    currencySymbol TEXT,
    currencySymbol_UTF8 TEXT,
    currencyConverter TEXT);
    """

sqlinsert = """ INSERT INTO responses VALUES (
    DateTime('now'),
    "obj['geoplugin_latitude']", 
    "obj[geoplugin_status]",
    "obj[geoplugin_delay]",
    "obj[geoplugin_credit]",
    "obj[geoplugin_city]",
    "obj[geoplugin_region]", 
    "obj[geoplugin_regionCode]",
    "obj[geoplugin_regionName]",
    "obj[geoplugin_areaCode]",
    "obj[geoplugin_dmaCode]",
    "obj[geoplugin_countryCode]",
    "obj[geoplugin_countryName]", 
    "obj[geoplugin_inEU]",
    "obj[geoplugin_euVATrate]",
    "obj[geoplugin_continentCode]",
    "obj[geoplugin_continentName]",
    "obj[geoplugin_latitude]",
    "obj[geoplugin_longitude]", 
    "obj[geoplugin_locationAccuracyRadius]",
    "obj[geoplugin_currencyCode]",
    "obj[geoplugin_timezone]",
    "obj[geoplugin_currencySymbol]",
    "obj[geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8]",
    "obj[geoplugin_currencyConverter]");
    """

# CREATE DATABASE
conn = sqlite3.connect("geoplugin.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(sqlcreatedb)

def dataInsert():
    c.execute(sqlinsert)
    conn.commit()

#While loof 60 seconds
# Every 60 seconds, write a line in database    
while True:

  dataInsert()
  time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - unixstarttime) % 60.0))
```

Comment: well, obviously with all these quotes you are inserting bunch of strings in the database.

Comment: @Hello Buran, true, but with out quotes, I am getting error. I copied only small part.     DateTime('now'),
    obj["geoplugin_latitude"], 
    obj["geoplugin_status"],
 
ERROR :

zeenmc@vista:~/Desktop/united$ python3 app.py 
44.8166    ###### <=  this is test from my code   print(obj["geoplugin_latitude"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 98, in <module>
    dataInsert()
  File "app.py", line 86, in dataInsert
    c.execute(sqlinsert, obj["geoplugin_currencyCode"])
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "["geoplugin_latitude"]": syntax error

Comment: Don't post import information in the comments, edit the question to include all important information. Also post both the code and the error. Don't expect us to guess what code produce that error. Check [ask].